# Element of order $2$ in $A_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am trying to solve this problem:

> Suppose $\sigma \in A_n$ is an element of order $2$. Prove that there exist $\pi \in S_n$ such that $\pi^2=\sigma$.

I have tried to do by induction on $n$. First we note that $n \geqslant 4$ since there is no elements of order $2$ in $S_1, S_2$ neither $S_3$. Now in $A_4$ the only elements of order $2$ are $(12)(34), (13)(24)$ and $(14)(23)$ it is not hard to see that $(12)(34)=(1324)^2$ and the same idea can be applied to the other two cases. Then we are done for case $n=4$.

Now we suppose that the property is true for $n=k$ and try to prove for $n=k+1$.

Question: Can I suppose that an element of order $2$ in $A_n$, $n>4$ is a product of an even number of distinct transpositions? Why?

If I can suppose this, then taking an element of order $2$ in $A_{k+1}$ we can separate the cases where the label $k+1$ appears and then apply the assumption?

Any idea about how to finish it and if I am in the right track?

Thank you guys!

Comment: What is the sign of a product of $m$ transpositions?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown This is $(-1)^m$, right?

Comment: Exactly! You did ask "Can I suppose that an element of order 2 in $A_n$ is a product of an even number of transpositions".

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown yes but it just proves that a product of transpositions is even. It has order $2$ just in case they are all distict, right?. Does it ensure that all elements of order two will have this form?

Comment: Yes, because written in a cycle decompositon, order of element $=lcm$ of lengths of disjoint cycles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have claimed, an element of order $2$ in $A_n$ is a product of even number of disjoint transposition. Afterall, in general, order of element in $S_n$ is the $lcm$ of the lengths of cycle in its cycle decomposition. And in $A_n$, elements consists of even no. of transpositions. So you're right.

Since $(12)(34)=(1324)^2$. Write $\sigma$ as product of pairs of disjoint transposition and conclude that it can be written similarly as squares. e.g. $(12)(34)(56)(78)=((1324)(5768))^2$

Answer (score 1):

If $\sigma \in A_n$ be an element of order $2$ then $$\sigma=\prod_{i=1}^{2k}(\alpha_i , \alpha_i^*)$$ for some $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,.....,\alpha_{2k}, \alpha_1^*, \alpha_2^*,......, \alpha_{2k}^* \in\{1,2,...,n\}$

Then the desired $π$ is $$π=\prod_{i=1}^{k}(\alpha_{2i-1} , \alpha_{2i}, \alpha_{2i-1}^*, \alpha_{2i}^*)$$